# Where does the new Outlook store signatures?

Tags: email, outlook, microsoft-office

I know that the old (Office 2021 and earlier) Outlook client stored signatures in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Signatures`.

Where does the new (post-2023) Outlook desktop client store its signature files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your accounts are hosted in Exchange Online, the signature settings are now stored in the cloud and can sync across devices.
See:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=60371
[image]

Based on my test in New Outlook preview, the same applies. When I tried to set signatures for outlook.com account or my Microsoft 365 account for business. After I create the signature from the Outlook client, I can see and use the signature settings in OWA as well, which can prove that the settings are indeed   stored in the cloud.

I've also tried capturing logs of the whole process of creating signatures in the New Outlook using ProcMon, found no clues about Outlook writing any signature related data locally either.

So taken in the round, the new (post-2023) Outlook desktop client doesn't store signature files locally.

Answer (score -1):

Try **C:\Users<YourUserName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures**

If you're not able to find it directly using that directory structure, you can open a terminal and cd to c:\Users<YourUserName>\ and then type:

```
dir /s Signatures
```

This will do a search for the word "Signatures" and show you the folders named the same. Good luck, G!